# How to fetch previous value (usePrevious hook) of useRef hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm using react and apexcharts to plot data in real time I receive from a bluetooth device.
To achieve smooth animation I had to create a render loop with withing a setTimeout() function which is triggered each second and use a useRef() hook which references the latest received data.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let bioFeedbackDataAnimation: number;
  bioFeedbackDataAnimation = window.setInterval(() => {
    if (stateRef.current) {
      ApexCharts.exec('realtime', 'updateSeries', stateRef.current, true);
    }
  }, 1000);
  return function cleanup() {
    window.clearInterval(bioFeedbackDataAnimation);
  };
}, []);
```

This works perfectly and the animation is smooth because time between renders is constant.

However, I now need to find out - inside the animation loop - if the data I'm plotting is the same as the data I plotted one second ago. I tried using the usePrevious hook, but all exemples I found are to fetch the previous value of a useState hook.

Is it possible to fetch the previous useRef.current value of a useRef hook? If so, how?
Thank you!

Comment: So, I'm not sure that we should use useState or some other hooks from react.
May we create just variable and put the current value? When you need last value take it from the variable

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find out how to do this.

The workaround I found consists of: When storing latest data, also store the previous data in another useState hook and then reference it as well using another stateRef hook.